# building reusable package in django

Tags: python, django

Am trying to build a reusbale package for django, the package contains multiple application since the project is quite large.

So, the structure, has am apps folder and inside it there is multiple apps payment, product, account..etc

As am trying to make the project re-usable, I created it in a different location of the source project and did a symbolic link to a root folder in the source project.

Now, when I want to install the apps, I have to write them one by one in the INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ('PACKAGE.apps.store',
                  'PACKAGE.apps.product',
                  'PACKAGE.apps.delivery',
                  'PACKAGE.apps.payment',
                  'PACKAGE.apps.store',
                  'PACKAGE.apps.cart',
                  'PACKAGE.apps.tax')
```

Is there a way, where I can only include 'PACKAGE' in my installed apps and perhaps use the package init to load the other modules?

I tried doing something like this in `PACKAGE/__init__.py`

```
from django.conf import settings as user_settings
from PACKAGE.conf import settings
user_settings.INSTALLED_APPS = user_settings.INSTALLED_APPS + settings.INSTALLED_APPS
```

But it didn't work, any one can advise on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that once the "from django.conf import settings" line has executed, settings are effectively immutable.

What I would do is invert the logic a bit. In PACKAGE/__init__.py. Something like:

```
def get_apps():
    apps = (
        'apps.store',
        'apps.other',
        ...
    )
    return [__name__ + '.' + x for x in apps]
```

Then just:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += get_apps()
```

in settings.py. I do this quite a bit to keep our settings.py manageable and it seems to work quite well.